# Adafruit-PlatformDetect unable to detect board

Tags: python, adafruit, platform-detection

Im trying to `import board` on a feather m4 expressx and getting the following error. Ive run the command it promoted me to do below and nothing changed. All libraries and software is updated. Im still getting the following error

```
    NotImplementedError: Adafruit-PlatformDetect version 3.26.0 was unable to identify the board and/or microcontroller running the Darwin platform. Please be sure you have the latest packages running: 'pip3 install --upgrade adafruit-blinka adafruit-platformdetect'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this but be aware that I can't test any of it as I don't have the hardware available.

1. execute this command in your cli: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
2. try to find this file (your path might be a bit different.):
   `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_platformdetect/constants/boards.py`

The output of the first command should give you a revision number that can be added to the baords.py

I know about other boards that where not yet added to the boards.py and had to be added manually until an update was released.

Please check if the number is already in the file and also create a copy of the file before changing it.